# Parse Amazon Order Response xml

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, linq-to-xml, amazon-mws

```
 <ListOrdersResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
 <ListOrdersResult>
<NextToken>xxxxxxxx</NextToken>
<CreatedBefore>07/31/2014 15:35:36</CreatedBefore>
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <AmazonOrderId>xxxxxx</AmazonOrderId>
    <SellerOrderId>xxxxxx</SellerOrderId>
    <PurchaseDate>07/21/2014 11:11:21</PurchaseDate>
    <LastUpdateDate>07/21/2014 21:41:23</LastUpdateDate>
    <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
    <FulfillmentChannel>AFN</FulfillmentChannel>
    <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
    <ShipServiceLevel>Standard</ShipServiceLevel>
    <ShippingAddress>
      <Name>xxxx</Name>
      <AddressLine1>xxxx</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2>xxxxx</AddressLine2>
      <City>xxxx</City>
      <StateOrRegion>xxx</StateOrRegion>
      <PostalCode>xxx</PostalCode>
      <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
      <Phone>xxxxxx</Phone>
    </ShippingAddress>
    <OrderTotal>
      <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
      <Amount>355.00</Amount>
    </OrderTotal>
    <NumberOfItemsShipped>1</NumberOfItemsShipped>
    <NumberOfItemsUnshipped>0</NumberOfItemsUnshipped>
    <PaymentExecutionDetail />
    <PaymentMethod>Other</PaymentMethod>
    <MarketplaceId>xxxxx</MarketplaceId>
    <BuyerEmail>xxxxx</BuyerEmail>
    <BuyerName>xxxxx</BuyerName>
    <ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>Standard</ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>
    <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
    <EarliestShipDate>07/21/2014 21:23:06</EarliestShipDate>
    <LatestShipDate>07/21/2014 21:23:06</LatestShipDate>
  </Order>
 </ListOrdersResult>
 <ResponseMetadata>
<RequestId>16a8a438-f774-4b17-824f-951a4cde7ddc</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrdersResponse>
```

I am trying to parse above mentioned Response.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);
            XNamespace ns = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
            var data = (from attrib in doc.Descendants(ns + "Order")
                       select new FormsPersistence
                       {

                           AmazonOrderID = (string)attrib.Element(ns+"AmazonOrderID").Value ?? string.Empty,
                           //MerchantOrderID = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "MerchantOrderID").Value ?? string.Empty,
                           //PurchaseDate = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "PurchaseDate").Value ?? string.Empty,
                           //OrderStatus = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderStatus").Value ?? string.Empty,
                           //ASIN = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "ASIN").Value ?? string.Empty,
                           //SKU = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "SKU").Value ?? string.Empty,
                          // ItemStatus = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "ItemStatus").Value ?? string.Empty,
                           //ProductName = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "ProductName").Value ?? string.Empty,
                           //Quantity = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "Quantity").Value ?? string.Empty,

                           //Amount = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "ItemPrice") == null ? string.Empty : (string)attrib.Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "ItemPrice").Element(ns + "Component").Element(ns + "Amount").Value,

                       }).ToList();
```

I am getting reference not set on an object error....
i have commented every thing just to test it out.even for first element its throwing exception.
I have tried everything. If someone could point me in right direction i will be grateful.

FormsPersistence is a class

```
class FormsPersistence
{

    public string AmazonOrderID { get; set; }
    public string MerchantOrderID { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string ASIN { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Instead of accessing `Value` property, it is more safe to simply cast `XElement` to string, for example : `AmazonOrderID = (string)attrib.Element(ns+"AmazonOrderID")`. Check if you still getting null reference exception this way

Comment: The element type "Orders" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</Orders>".

Comment: Value property is throwing error just because i am not able to reference the node.by removing value property i am getting no return value.

Comment: @Kokkie i skipped that tag while copying but its there in my original response file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not checking the entire property, but for the first it is only a matter of different case. Note that XML node name is case sensitive, so `AmazonOrderID` should've been `AmazonOrderId` :

```
var data = (from attrib in doc.Descendants(ns + "Order")
            select new
            {

                AmazonOrderID = (string)attrib.Element(ns + "AmazonOrderId"),
                .....
                .....

            }).ToList();
```

So the first suggestion is look at your code more closely. Another suggestion is as stated in my comment, simply cast the `XElement` to suitable value instead of getting `XElement.Value` property.

**UPDATE :**

Okay, I have seen the entire property. There is no such element named `MerchantOrderID` and `OrderItem` in the XML sample, so all lines in your code trying to access those elements will definately trigger exception.